# ADF pipeline architecture and parametrization for parallel copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to implement parallel copy activity pipeline and I wonder about its architecture. To sum up, I'll have 3 copy activity goes from legacy db to datalake, and two from sharepoint. Is it good idea to put just 5 copy activity in single pipeline and have it run from there, or it will quickly become a bottleneck? For those 3 copy activities from db to datalake, I basically will use same db, schema but different tables and queries. Is it worth to do ForEach and pass whole queries as parameters to query? I guess then I don't have a parallel run, but a sequential
Something like that will do the job? Tables are not so big, up to 10 mln rows
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem in this way:

1. Store connection strings, db name, schemas,etc. as metadata in
   either a sql db or .json file. Maybe store sensitive information in
   your KV and just the references to it in you metadata.
2. Create one Main Executor pipeline per source
3. Do a lookup to this metadata location and then run a single copy activity inside a for each loop. For each source type/connection.

By doing that, you can scale your pipeline by including new sources easily and in a consistent way. Furthermore, you can adjust parallelism and the number of concurrent executions easily and dynamically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We're in the middle of new architecture implementation and yet we dont use metadata pipelines.. soon :). However your approach is structured the way one need to run two exectutors in order to load whole data? Can't it be done one executor pipeline for all, doesnt matter what source data, so one pipeline which executes 5 copy activity with paths, db names etc set inside copy activity? Can it work? Also where did you wanted to store for example json file - in datalake, in directory where files will land?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but it would not be scalable. Technically,yes you can have as much copy activities as you want from as many sources in your pipeline. That said, it would be a nightmare to debug, monitor, log and support. Regarding storage of such "helper" files, it comes down to what your architecture is and what you have access to. I would personally prefer to store it in the storage account where my ingested files land. Not in their folders, but in a separate dedicated one.